# Ruby on Rails convention for date time format from external source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given rails has a convention for most common tasks, is there a format of date/time data that ruby/rails ingests most easily, or which it 'prefers'?

I will have date/time data coming from an external source, and I can choose how it's formatted (but it not be easy to change later). I have researched and found two recommended formats:

1. A string of format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`
2. Unix epoch time (i.e. number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970)

Does rails deal more easily with one of these formats over the other (or is there another convention?)

Additional note: I can see from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibJE_T4w3Bo) talk that it's almost always best to store time in UTC, so I have that much figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that Ruby on Rails default to using the UTC time zone at least in the database.

I do not see a strong convention what time string format Rails prefers, but I would always choose [ISO 8601](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/): `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ'`

Comment: I researched further and can see that format used widely. I also note the `T` is just a literal to separate the time and date, and the `Z` stands for 'zero offset' (i.e. UTC). Also, it's wonderful that this format is instantly recognised by rails with (example) `"2019-02-07T01:16:19.000Z".to_datetime`